# Ошибка при передачи объекта из родительского компонента в дочерний Angular

Tags: json, angular2, typescript

Есть у меня JSON объект который я получаю с сервера:

```
{
    "header": {
        "logo": "CoolLogo",
        "logo_discriptor": "Інвестеційна платформа",
        "discriptor": "Примножимо гроші разом",
        "lang_list": [
            "Eng",
            "Укр"
        ]
    },
    "body": null,
    "footer": null
}
```

На фронте создал объект в который маплю данный джейсон:

```
import { JsonProperty } from 'json-typescript-mapper';

export class Header {
    @JsonProperty('logo')
    logo: string;
    @JsonProperty('logo_discriptor')
    logoDiscriptor: string;
    @JsonProperty('discriptor')
    discriptor: string;
    @JsonProperty('lang_list')
    langList: string[];

    constructor() {
        this.logo = undefined;
        this.logoDiscriptor = undefined;
        this.discriptor = undefined;
        this.langList = undefined;
    }
}

export class Body {

}

export class Footer {

}

export class LangModel {
    @JsonProperty({clazz: Header, name: 'header'})
    header: Header;

    @JsonProperty({clazz: Body, name: 'body'})
    body: Body;

    @JsonProperty({clazz: Footer, name: 'footer'})
    footer: Footer;

    constructor() {
        this.header = undefined;
        this.body = undefined;
        this.footer = undefined;
    }
}
```

и соответственно есть компонент `(app.component.ts)` в котором я через сервис его получаю и заливаю в переменную:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpService } from '../app/mtg-services/http.mtg-service';
import { LangModel} from '../app/mtg-models/answers.mtg-model';
import { deserialize } from 'json-typescript-mapper';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [HttpService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  langModel: LangModel;
  defaultLang = 'Eng';
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.httpService.postLangModel(this.defaultLang)
      .subscribe(
        (data: LangModel) => {
          this.langModel = deserialize(LangModel, data);
          console.log(this.langModel);
        },
        error => console.log(error)
      );
  }
}
```

на данном этапе все работает без ошибок в консоли, данные выкачиваются и заливаются в переменную. Далее мне необходимо пробросить этот объект (вернее его составные части в дочерние компонеты). Для примера приведу один из дочерних компонентов:

```
import { Input, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { LangModel, Header} from '../mtg-models/answers.mtg-model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header-section',
  templateUrl: './header-section.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header-section.component.css']
})
export class HeaderSectionComponent implements OnInit {

  header: Header;

  @Input()
  set HeaderData(langModel: LangModel) {
    this.header = langModel.header;
    console.log(langModel.header);
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Делаю это через свойства в родительском компонете `(app.component.html)`:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <app-header-section [HeaderData]='langModel.header'></app-header-section>
    <app-body-section></app-body-section>
    <app-footer-section></app-footer-section>
</div>
```

И тут в консоли появляются множества ошибок, мол не возможно прочесть свойство `'header'` - оно не опредлено.

[image: пример ошибки в консоли]

Уповаю на помощь комьюнити.

Comment: потому что на первой итерации рендеринга этого свойства не существует и сеттится оно асинхронно, в таких случаях используется safe navigation оператор - `[HeaderData]="langModel?.header"`. И именуй свойства в `camelCase` -> `headerData`. Это во-первых, во-вторых ты в `headerData` передаешь `langModel.header`, хотя в сеттере у тебя тип `LangModel` и опять обращаешься к `header` - может должно быть `[headerData]="langModel"`?

Comment: @ overthesanity, огромное спасибо, все ошибки исчезли и все заработало.

Comment: @РоманТимохов,хочу обратить внимание, ```json-typescript-mapper``` устаревший и не работающий в должной мере пакет. Воспользуйся лучше другим.

Comment: @Sergey Rogachev, я новичек в Angular, что первое пройстейшее  нашел, то и применил. Буду рад если посоветуете что-то популярное, что все используют.

Comment: @РоманТимохов, ```js-ts-mapper```

Comment: что-то не похоже чтобы этот пакет был мега популярен. Я так понимаю вы один из его создателей и оставили здесь о нем упоминание? @overthesanity какой бы пакет посоветовали вы?

Comment: смотря для каких целей, я не хочу вдаваться в контекст, но увидел что ты написал про маппинг, https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer - этот пакет используется на продакшене огромными компаниями и довольно успешно был применен на большом кол-ве проектов